# Print a triangle right to left

Tags: javascript

I'm begining with programming. I'm using javascript.

For practice, I print a triangle like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

but I want to print right to left, like this:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

So, with my noob knowledge, I wrote this code:

```
var line = '';

var size = 5;

for (var i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= size; j++) {
        if (j == size - i) {
            line += '#';
            if (i != 0) {
                for (var k = j; k < size; k++) {
                    line += '#';
                }
            }
        } else {
            line += ' ';
        }
    }

    line += '\n';  
}

console.log(line);
```

It works! But I think it's awful.

Could someone give me some advice?

Thanks very much!

Comment: This should be on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this.

```
var N = 5;//based on your input
for (var i=0;i<N;i++) {
        var str = "";
        for (var j=0;j<N;j++) {
            if (j >= N-i-1) {
                str += "*";
            } else {
                str += " ";
            }
        }
        console.log(str);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A little shorter:

```
var size = 5;
for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
    var txt = ""
    for (j=1;j<=size;j++) {
        txt+=" *"[(j>=size-i)+0]
    }
    console.log(txt)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one also

```
function print(n){
for (var i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        var str = "";
        for (var j=0;j<n;j++) {
            str+= (j >= n-i)?"*":" "
       }
        console.log(str);
    }}
print(9)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function staircase(n) {
  // Write your code here
  let output = ""
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    output += " ";
  }
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    output = output.slice(1, output.length);
    output += "#";
    console.log(output)
  }
}
```